# Properly using a newly-instantiated user control from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a number of user controls which I wrote, worked great but am now dismayed at the fact that they don't seem to work at all if I add them dynamically. That is to say, when I put them directly into my ASPX code, they work fine, but not when I created them via the `new` keyword and then insert them somewhere.

Consider the following control:

```
class MyUserControl: UserControl {
    public string Text { get => this.lblChildLabel; set => this.lblChildLabel = value; } 
}
```

Lets suppose that on the front, it only has a single label named `lblChildLabel`.

If I put the above control into my code, I can easily control it:

```
// In page_prerender
theControl.Text = "Anything";
```

And it displays fine.

However, if I were to instantiate it "manually", as such:

```
var aNewControl = new MyUserControl();
aNewControl.Text = "Something"; // Exception: MyUserControl's lblChildLabel is not set to an instance of an object
```

This doesn't seem to be an issue with any built-in controls.

Any ideas?

Comment: `<%@Register...` controls you are planning to use on your `.aspx` page.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Yup I have that. Just double checked. When I drag-dropped them into the page (prior to the dynamic stuff), it got added automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being a good SO citizen, I'm reporting back on the solution.

In short, this is wrong:

```cs
var aNewControl = new MyUserControl();
aNewControl.Text = "Something";
```

This is correct:

```cs
var aNewControl = (MyUserControl) Page.LoadControl("~/User Controls/MyControl.ascx");
aNewControl.Text = "Something";
```

The former doesn't run through the normal life-cycle while the latter does.